# "Show in folder" function in chrome packaged app

Tags: filesystems, google-chrome-app

I want implement a function in chrome app. my app received file from network, and i saved it in the local filesystem. how could i implement the function "show in folder". the same as browser to show download files. or implement the function "open file".

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i want implement the function in a chrome app, not an extension. And chrome app have no API like chrome.downloads. For the file i want to show in local file system, i can get the Entry of it. Do you have any idea of how to implement it?

Comment: You'll have to write a separate utility for that, it would run in OS natively and [communicate with your app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#native-messaging).

Comment: But my file is received from other app with socket, i think it can't be saved with downloads API. So there is no way to implement it within a chrome app?

Comment: chrome.downloads API has nothing to do with a native OS utility, it's a completely different approach. See the documentation for [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging).

Comment: I know what you mean, create an extension and use app  communicate with extension to handle the file. But my file receive method can not change. I can't use "get" or "post" to get a file with url from a webserver. I have to get file with socket.

Comment: No, it means a native OS program.

Comment: My program runs in chromebook, but the document is all about windows osx and ubuntu, is that approach works for me? I am not familiar with the document. And l will check it more carefully.

Comment: See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328803